# Python program uses 2.6 method, but came with python24.dll

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x

I am running a downloaded Python program (.pyc file) that throws the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'`

Apparently, `str.format` is a 2.6+ method. When I check the program's directory, one of the files that is included in the distribution is `python24.dll`.

I tried adding `python26.dll` to the directory, but it doesn't work. I tried to rename `python26.dll` to `python24.dll`, but still no luck.

Anything to do other than recompile the original Python code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

.pyc file cannot be used across multiple versions. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/